# RPi.GPIO library limitation - add_event_detect cache

Tags: gpio, python, rpi.gpio

How many callback events is cached in add_event_detect function? In my example below `start_thread` is executed just twice, but it is fired up five times (by the loop). To me it looks, that GPIO library is not able to hold more than 2 callback requests. or have i missed anything?

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

start_thread_id = 1
_gpin = 10
i = 0


def start_thread(channel):
    global start_thread_id
    print("_***** F: start_thread called")
    for i in range(0, 5):
        print("doing job for thread #{}:".format(start_thread_id))
        time.sleep(0.3)
    start_thread_id += 1
    return


GPIO.setup(
    _gpin,
    GPIO.IN,
    pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP
    )

GPIO.add_event_detect(
    _gpin, GPIO.RISING,
    callback=start_thread,
    bouncetime=5
    )

while True:
    if i <= 5:
        print("_gpin change #{}".format(i))
        GPIO.setup(_gpin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
        time.sleep(.1)
        GPIO.setup(_gpin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
    else:
        time.sleep(40)
        break
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no reason to doubt that your tests are correct for the RPi.GPIO Python module.

If you need to have more events queued you could use the [pigpio Python module](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html).  It will queue up hundreds of events.

pigpio [callbacks](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#callback)

Comment: Thanks, I will give a try to `pigpio`

Comment: Confirming the `pigpio` works as expected in terms of events caching